# Swift Class/Protocol is not recognised by Xcode compiler or Auto Complete

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

When you create a new file in your Swift Xcode project, e.g.: a new class.  It gets created successfully however it seems unable to be used or found in the auto complete.  Eg: I create a class FooBase and then try and create a second class that inherits from FooBase -

```
Class Foo:FooBase
```

FooBase does not appear in the auto complete and the compiler throws an unknown type error.

Steps to Reproduce:
1) File -> New File -> Create a FooBase.swift
2) File -> New File -> Create a Foo.swift 
3) Try and inherit FooBase in Foo.  Eg: Class Foo:FooBase

Other classes I have created are in the autocomplete list, and can be picked, as are the base strings/ints etc.

Its driving me mad.  It seems to happen fairly randomly and about 80% of the time.  Am I doing something stupid?

Comment: I've head this problem as well, but it seems so intermittent as to be untraceable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be an issue with OS X Yosemite Beta.  I've subsquently tried it in OS X Mavericks and I don't get the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the steps you've listed, it seems that you created a swift file FooBase, but left it empty. Is there a class declaration in FooBase.swift?

A .swift file doesn't imply that you've created a class. ;)

Comment: laziness on my part.  For the purposes of the example free free to add a variable or init() method.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
//FooBase.swift
import Foundation

class FooBase {
    var fooBar = 1
}

//Foo.swift
import Foundation

class Foo: FooBase {
    let foo = FooBase().fooBar

}
```

Note that the code completion did not pop up with FooBase when I was typing `class Foo: FooBase`.  But it recognized it once I finished.  You could out both classes in the same file for ease of demonstrating.

Comment: This is exactly what doesn't seem to work for me??!?  If I combine the classes together as in your example it works fine but if I separate them then it breaks. I was wondering if it had something to do with compilation order?

Comment: Can you post your project to github?  This works for me in separate files.