# New Swift File in an IOS project is not recognized by xCode

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am running MacOSX 10.10.3 (Yosemite) and XCode Version 6.4 (6E35b).  I am trying out Swift tutorial http://www.raywenderlich.com/74904/swift-tutorial-part-2-simple-ios-app.

But when I create new Swift File named TipCalculatorModel I can't seem to use the class on ViewController class.

```
let tipCalc = TipCalculatorModel(...) //Use of unresolved identifier 'TipCalculatorModel'
```

I verified the TipCalculatorModel's Target Membership and the item checked is only the project name (TipCalculator, TipCalculatorTest is unchecked)

Can anyone point me what I may have missed?  Or is this issue with the current version of xcode or OSX like what's in [Swift Class/Protocol is not recognised by Xcode compiler or Auto Complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26147020/swift-class-protocol-is-not-recognised-by-xcode-compiler-or-auto-complete)

Comment: Is there a class named TipCalculatorModel in your TipCalculatorModel.swift file? In the tutorial they make it from another file/class, maybe you forgot a step somewhere.

Comment: Oh crap you're right @EricD.  I copied the class in the first step and missed to rename it to TipCalculatorModel.  Thanks so much for you help!